# Emacs or VIm with a serious extensible visual frontend?

Tags: editor

Are there any emacs or VIm clones (on any platform or browser) that work with all the standard plugins/"modes" for emacs or vim and also provide a significant amount of "visual" code navigation, traversing, editing, etc?

"Visual" means using buttons or trees or menus that you click with a mouse, or some presentation of code/data beyond what can be done in console emulation.

Additionally, "visual" editors should have some amount of integration between the visual features and the standard api of the underlying console-based editor; for example, (this might be terrible in practice) a way for "org mode" to expose some of its commands as buttons or drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

xemacs or gvim should probably suit your needs. I know xemacs, at least, is fairly like what you describe with buttons and menus, though I don't think it really presents code any differently from the console version of emacs.

Links to each:
http://www.xemacs.org/
http://www.vim.org/download.php